# how should i put conditional statements on a node drupal 8?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I am new to drupal 8. I want something like this:

```
{% if node.2 %}
...............
.........
{% endif %}
```

what is the correct code for this? In back end I have created several nodes like node/1, node/2. I want to put a condition in node.html.twig.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `node`? How did you pass it towards the view?

Answer (score 0):

Got to twig [documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/):

```
{% if node is not empty %}
   {% for oneNode as node %}
      {{ oneNode.title }}
      {{ oneNode.body }}
      ..................
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this way....

```
{% if node.id == 2 %}
  YOUR CODE..............
{% endif %}
```